# How to append the id of li elements in the jQuery UI selectable multiples

Tags: jquery, user-interface, selectable

Okay, so I'm trying to integrate the [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) plugin selectable (grid), and I like how it posts the selected indexes back. Here is what I would like to do:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
            $( ".ui-selected").each(function() {
                 var index = $( "#selectable li" ).attr('id');
                                   // But I want the ids of all the selected elements,
                                   // but the id of the first is just getting copied on my site!
                result.append( "#" + ( index + 1 ) );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
            $( ".ui-selected").each(function() {
                 var index = $( this ).attr('id'); 
                result.append( "#" + ( index + 1 ) );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfection! , any idea how i can pass the selected values to an $.post request?

Comment: `$( "#selectable" ).serialize()` you just have to pass this to $.post

Comment: but i try to alert them to the srceen and there retuning blank ??